# Get permissions at installing time

Tags: android, android-permissions, target-sdk, android-8.1-oreo

I want to get permissions at **install time** in my Android application. For this reason, **I had to downgrade the targetsdk from 27 to 22**. Currently, my `build.gradle` information is as follows:

```
minSDK 17 
targetSdkVersion 22
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'
```

and in my application, these libraries have been used:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
```

The problem is that it is not installed on my Android 8.1 (Pixel phone), but on other phones there is no problem with the lower Android versions.

Comment: If you are upgrading an App which is already on store with target>22 then you can't do that. If not What error you getting on Pixel during installation ?

Comment: `it is not installed on my Android 8.1(pixel phone)` share your crash log than

Comment: "i want get permissions at installing time in my android application.For this reason, I had to downgrade the targetsdk from 27 to 22" -- bear in mind that [you will not be able to ship updates to your app on the Play Store starting later in 2018](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't request permission at install time, this is outdated, because it was used like in 5.x and less versions of Android, now you need to request permissions inside the app

> the user grants the permission either when they install the app (on
>   Android 5.1.1 and lower) or while running the app (on Android 6.0 and
>   higher).

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring.html

Comment: But many apps still get permissions at the install time, and they are not in trouble with Android 8.1

Comment: yes , but you should consider not doing it and target highest sdk

Comment: because if you want to do it you will need to decrease all your compile versions and all your sdk version

Comment: What problems will happen?